# NEED help regarding view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to run a view named ViewMessages.php on codeigniter that will display a list of messages, with details of the poster, content and time of each. All this information regarding the poster and etc is already available in a database that is linked to my file.  I am new to codeigniter and PHP so I was wondering if anyone can help me with how to go about the code?

Comment: If you are new to `PHP` why are you using a framework? First get to grips with pure `PHP` then move on to a framework. You need some understanding of `PHP` to be able to use frameworks.

Comment: Like I know the basics of PHP mainly Im new to codeigniter

Comment: controller -> model (fetch data from the database, put it in an array, send it back to controller) -> controller (send the data received from the model to your view) -> view (do whatever you want to with the data)

Answer (score 0):

*Which CodeIgniter version are you running?*

If CodeIgniter 2.*. Try looking at this page:
[CodeIgniter Guides - Views](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Under **Loading a View** it shows you the code of how to load your ViewMessages.php inside your controller

Comment: Im running version 3.0.2 !

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Just follow the tutorials of the CodeIgniter docs and you will very soon be able to make you assignment :)